# Where is this title coming from

Tags: php, magento

I am using magento and i have this code in my left_nav.phtml

```
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');?>      
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories();?>

<!-- BEGIN SIDE-NAV-CATEGORY -->  
<div class="side-nav-categories">
<div class="block-title">
<?php echo ('Categories');?>
<?php   var_dump(get_class($this)); ?>
</div><!--block-title-->
<?php if (count($_categories) > 0):  ?>
<!-- BEGIN BOX-CATEGORY -->  
<div class="box-content box-category">
<ul>
<!-- Subcategory -->
<?php 
//get the current category
$_cat = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation();
$currentCat = $_cat->getCurrentCategory();

//get the children of the current category
$subCats =    Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($currentCat->getId())->getChildren()    ;

//get sub category ids
$subCatIds = explode(',',$subCats);
?>

<?php if (count($subCatIds) > 1): ?>
 <ul>
  <?php foreach($subCatIds as $subCatId): ?>
   <?php $subCat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCatId);     ?>
   <?php if($subCat->getIsActive()): ?>
    <li>
     <?php //display category image
     if($subCat->getImageUrl()): ?>
      <img src="<?php echo $subCat->getImageUrl(); ?>" />
     <?php endif; ?>
     <a href="<?php echo $subCat->getUrl(); ?>">
     <?php echo $subCat->getName(); ?>
     </a>
    </li>
   <?php endif; ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
 </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
<!-- Subcategory-->
 </ul>
</div><!--box-content box-category-->
<?php endif; ?>
</div><!--side-nav-categories-->
```

in the div class block-title it changes the title to search vehicle by category.

where can i find the code that defines block-title? so i can change the title to the root category name?

Comment: if i delete the block-title it shows up as categories from the echo 'categories' code in another file is creating the title using the block-title but i cant find the source for the block-title.

Comment: Not sure where it shows.

Comment: on the front end it displays 'categories' and when the site loads categories changes to a string loaded from block-title block.  where would i be able to find the file it calls to?

Comment: what i mean is what would the code look like that defines div class="block-title" and where is it located because that class is changing the way <?php echo ('Categories');?> shows up on the front end.  and without that tag the styling of it completely changes.

Comment: found what i was looking for in 3columns.phtml it was a java script excecuting a change to .block-title

Comment: <script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery('.side-nav-categories .block-title').html('Search Vehicle by Categories');
});
</script>